# SharedPrefs в receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences, broadcast-receiver

В общем,есть receiver для обнаружения звонков. В нем мне нужно создать sharedPreference и сохранить данные. Проблема в том что если я это делаю в activity или service то всё хорошо, но если здесь то оно ничего не сохраняет. Как правильно это сделать? может не тот context?

Заранее спасибо.

Вот код ресивера:

```
package com.example.callrecorder.receiver

///imports

open class CallRecordReceiver(private var callRecord: CallRecord, private val context: Context) : PhoneCallReceiver() {

companion object {
    private val TAG = CallRecordReceiver::class.java.simpleName

    const val ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"
    const val ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"
    const val EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER = "android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER"
    private var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null
}

private var audioFile: File? = null
private var isRecordStarted = false

override fun onIncomingCallReceived(context: Context, number: String?, start: Date) {
}

override fun onIncomingCallAnswered(context: Context, number: String?, start: Date) {
    val prefs = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("ring", true)
    editor.apply()

    startRecord(context, "incoming_"+System.currentTimeMillis(), number)

}

override fun onIncomingCallEnded(context: Context, number: String?, start: Date, end: Date) {
    val prefs = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("ring", false)
    editor.apply()
    stopRecord(context)
}

override fun onOutgoingCallStarted(context: Context, number: String?, start: Date) {
    val prefs = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("ring", true)
    editor.apply()
    startRecord(context, "outgoing_"+System.currentTimeMillis(), number)
}

override fun onOutgoingCallEnded(context: Context, number: String?, start: Date, end: Date) {
    val prefs = android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("ring", false)
    editor.apply()
    stopRecord(context)
}

override fun onMissedCall(context: Context, number: String?, start: Date) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = start
    val millis = cal.timeInMillis
    writemissedcall(number.toString(),millis.toString(),context)
}

// Derived classes could override these to respond to specific events of interest
protected open fun onRecordingStarted(context: Context, callRecord: CallRecord, audioFile: File?) {}

protected open fun onRecordingFinished(context: Context, callRecord: CallRecord, audioFile: File?) {}

private fun startRecord(context: Context, seed: String, phoneNumber: String?) {
    try {
        val isSaveFile = PrefsHelper.readPrefBool(context, CallRecord.PREF_SAVE_FILE)
        LogUtils.i(TAG, "isSaveFile: $isSaveFile")

        // is save file?
        if (!isSaveFile) {
            return
        }

        if (isRecordStarted) {
            LogUtils.i(TAG, "One")
            try {
                LogUtils.i(TAG, "two")
                //recorder?.stop()  // stop the recording
                stopRecord(context)
                startRecord(context, seed, phoneNumber)
            } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
                LogUtils.i(TAG, "Three")
                // RuntimeException is thrown when stop() is called immediately after start().
                // In this case the output file is not properly constructed ans should be deleted.
                LogUtils.d(TAG, "RuntimeException: stop() is called immediately after start()")
                audioFile?.delete()
            }

            releaseMediaRecorder()
            isRecordStarted = false
        } else {
            LogUtils.i(TAG, "Four")
            if (prepareAudioRecorder(context, seed, phoneNumber)) {
                recorder!!.start()
                isRecordStarted = true
                onRecordingStarted(context, callRecord, audioFile)
                LogUtils.i(TAG, "record start")
            } else {
                LogUtils.i(TAG, "Five")
                releaseMediaRecorder()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        releaseMediaRecorder()
    } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        releaseMediaRecorder()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        releaseMediaRecorder()
    }
}

private fun stopRecord(context: Context) {
    LogUtils.i(TAG, "record stop 1")
    try {
        if (recorder != null && isRecordStarted) {
            releaseMediaRecorder()
            isRecordStarted = false
            onRecordingFinished(context, callRecord, audioFile)
            LogUtils.i(TAG, "record stop 2")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        releaseMediaRecorder()
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

private fun prepareAudioRecorder(
    context: Context, seed: String, phoneNumber: String?
): Boolean {
    try {
        var fileName = PrefsHelper.readPrefString(context, CallRecord.PREF_FILE_NAME)
        val dirPath = PrefsHelper.readPrefString(context, CallRecord.PREF_DIR_PATH)
        val dirName = PrefsHelper.readPrefString(context, CallRecord.PREF_DIR_NAME)
        val showSeed = PrefsHelper.readPrefBool(context, CallRecord.PREF_SHOW_SEED)
        val showPhoneNumber =
            PrefsHelper.readPrefBool(context, CallRecord.PREF_SHOW_PHONE_NUMBER)
        val outputFormat = PrefsHelper.readPrefInt(context, CallRecord.PREF_OUTPUT_FORMAT)
        val audioSource = PrefsHelper.readPrefInt(context, CallRecord.PREF_AUDIO_SOURCE)
        val audioEncoder = PrefsHelper.readPrefInt(context, CallRecord.PREF_AUDIO_ENCODER)

        val sampleDir = File("$dirPath/$dirName")

        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
            sampleDir.mkdirs()
        }

        val fileNameBuilder = StringBuilder()
        fileNameBuilder.append(fileName)
        fileNameBuilder.append("_")

        if (showSeed) {
            fileNameBuilder.append(seed)
            fileNameBuilder.append("_")
        }

        if (showPhoneNumber && phoneNumber != null) {
            fileNameBuilder.append(phoneNumber)
            fileNameBuilder.append("_")
        }

        fileName = fileNameBuilder.toString()

        val suffix: String
        when (outputFormat) {
            MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB -> {
                suffix = ".amr"
            }
            MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB -> {
                suffix = ".amr"
            }
            MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4 -> {
                suffix = ".mp4"
            }
            MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP -> {
                suffix = ".3gp"
            }
            else -> {
                suffix = ".amr"
            }
        }

        audioFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, suffix, sampleDir)

        recorder = MediaRecorder()
        recorder?.apply {
            setAudioSource(audioSource)
            setOutputFormat(outputFormat)
            setAudioEncoder(audioEncoder)
            setOutputFile(audioFile!!.absolutePath)
            setOnErrorListener { _, _, _ -> }
        }

        try {
            recorder?.prepare()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            LogUtils.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.message)
            releaseMediaRecorder()
            return false
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            LogUtils.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.message)
            releaseMediaRecorder()
            return false
        }

        return true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        LogUtils.e(e)
        e.printStackTrace()
        return false
    }
}

private fun releaseMediaRecorder() {
    recorder?.apply {
        reset()
        release()
    }
    recorder = null
}

private fun writemissedcall(num: String, time: String, context: Context) {
    println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    println("!$num!$time!")
    val prefs: SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    val call: String
    call = "!$num@$time?"
    val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putString("missedcalls", call)
    editor.apply()
}
}
```

Comment: Можете проверить свою догадку с контекстом, используя `context.getApplicationContext()` в качестве аргумента для `SharedPreferences`. Думаю, ошибка в `getDefaultSharedPreferences`, который [возвращает разные `SharedPreferences`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10786172)

Comment: я попробывал но не помогло(

Comment: Может кому-то поможет.я читал sharedpref в java а записывал в kotlin. Я переписал receiver с kotlin на java и все начало работать. Я не знаю с чем это связано но это работает

Answer (score 0):

По логике настройки сохраняются, чтобы при перезапуске приложения они не исчезали. Следовательно записывать их надо в onSaveInstanceState, а считывать в onRestoreInstanceState.